# jvectormap merge two maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I'm trying to merge two jvectormaps: [italy-regions](http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/italy-regions/) and [italy-provinces](http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/italy-provinces/), i
would like to achieve something similar to the [drill-down example](http://jvectormap.com/examples/drill-down/) or even just have the map diveded both in regions and provinces.
I think i cannot use `multimap` like in the demo because `italy-provinces` map is just one script with all the provinces inside, so the main function for retrieve the map of each region is useless:

```
mapUrlByCode: function(code, multiMap){
  return '/js/us-counties/jquery-jvectormap-data-'+
         code.toLowerCase()+'-'+
         multiMap.defaultProjection+'-en.js';
}
```

In this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpZYKb) i've reproduced something similar to what i'm trying to achieve.
Obviously this solution is really bad, because i'm using two maps and once i click in a random region of the first map the second map will not zoom, so the two maps looks not synchronized.
Someone know or can suggest a way to achieve what i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, the great jVectorMap also supports focus on more than one region, so what you need is just to create the association among regions and provinces and invoke that functions twice.

I revorked a bit your code to be in some way more "explicit" about *Provinces* and *Regions*:

HTML:

```
<div id="map-provinces"></div> 
<div id="map-regions"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#map-provinces{
  height:500px;
  width: 500px;
  left:-500px;
  opacity:0.5;
}
#map-regions{
  top: 8px; /* Body margin wasn't set correctly in the CodePen */ 
  position : absolute;
  height:500px;
  width: 500px;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Here is how i do it with the Region of Sicily, up to you to complete this example with the whole list of Province codes:

```
var provinces ={"IT-82": ["TP","PA","AG","CL","EN","ME","CT","RG","SR"]};

$('#map-provinces').vectorMap({
   map: 'it_mill'
});
$('#map-regions').vectorMap({
  map: 'it_regions_mill',
  backgroundColor : 'white',
  zoomOnScroll : false,
  zoomMin : 0,
  zoomMax :220,
  regionStyle :{
    initial: {
        fill: 'blue',
        "fill-opacity": 1,
        stroke: 'none',
        "stroke-width": 0,
        "stroke-opacity": 1
    },
    hover: {
      "fill-opacity": 1,
      cursor: 'pointer'
    },
    selected: {
      fill: 'blue',
      "fill-opacity": 1,
    },
    selectedHover: {
      "fill-opacity": 1,
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }
  },
  onRegionClick: function(e,  code,  isSelected,  selectedRegions){
    var codes = [];
    provinces[code].forEach(function(province) {
      codes.push("IT-"+province);
    });
    $('#map-regions').vectorMap('get','mapObject').setFocus({region: code});
    $('#map-provinces').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').setFocus({regions: codes});
  }
});
```

Whit that in mind, you can easily implement the drill-down sample provided  on the jVectorMap website, and have both maps correctly aligned after the zoom on region click, like in this picture below, where both overlapped maps are displayed, like you did it in your CodePen:

[image: Sicily Provinces]

Comment: wow thanks man its looks great, just one more question, if i zoom out the first map the second map (provinces) will not zoom out. So there is a way i can bind zoom buttons in boths maps?

Comment: yes, of course, but that would be another question, how to synchronize the `viewport` of two overlapped maps... Moreover, after you focused a region, you would need to swap the maps, so that provinces will be the current foreground map and you can click on it. You agree?

Comment: Yay that would be a nice feature, i'm trying to do some attempts,possibly can i post link to other question here?

Comment: even if your answer is correct i figured out a better way of doing this, without specify provinces but only synchronizing the 2 maps.